# C# PDFsharp output RTF text

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have data in SQL that is in RTF as it contains a lot of superscript characters. I am trying to print the data on a PDF using PDFsharp (not MigraDoc) using DrawString, however, as I expected, it just shows the RTF string...

I tried putting it in a RichTextBox and then retrieving the Text property, this gives the correct plain text but not in superscript format, which I need.

Can anyone tell me how to correctly output the RTF data?

Answer (score 0):

First from [FAQ](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx?HL=rtf#Can_I_use_PDFsharp_to_convert_HTML_or_RTF_to_PDF_10) of pdfsharp:

> **Can I use PDFsharp to convert HTML or RTF to PDF?**
>
> No, not "out of the
> box", and we do not plan to write such a converter in the near future.
>
> Yes, PDFsharp with some extra code can do it. But we do not supply
> that extra code. On NuGet and other sources you can find a third party
> library "HTML Renderer for PDF using PdfSharp" that converts HTML to
> PDF. And there may be other libraries for the same or similar
> purposes, too. Maybe they work for you, maybe they get you started.

A workaround I think is using [`DrawToBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a `RichTextBox` to render the RTF string into an image, then use `DrawImage` to put it in the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Using a RichTextBox would also be my approach, but I would select only a single character in the text and query the relevant properties (subscript, superscript, maybe also bold, italic, underline, and anything else you need). And when any of those properties changes, draw the text you collected so far and continue collecting characters for the new set of properties until any relevant property changes.

I would probably use MigraDoc so I would not have to deal with line-breaks in my code, but that is up to you. I would not create bitmaps for the text as this voids the advantages of the PDF format.